# How do you run Python code using Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

I'm trying to run Python code for testing and debugging using Emacs. How should I debug and run code in *.py files ? I tried using the `M-x compile` commands . Using `M-x compile`, I get a compilation buffer that crashes (It says Python is compiling, but then nothing happens).

Answer (score 54):

If you are using emacs24 this should be the default (in emacs23 you need python.el, not python-mode.el):

In a python buffer:

- C-c C-z : open a python shell
- C-c C-c : run the content of the buffer in the opened python shell
- C-c C-r : run the selected region in the python shell

default python shell is "python", if you need to use ipython you can use this conf in your .emacs

```
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
 python-shell-interpreter-args "--colors=Linux --profile=default"
 python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-completion-setup-code
 "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
 python-shell-completion-module-string-code
 "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
 python-shell-completion-string-code
 "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

provided that you have ipython installed in your system of course :)

ipython>=5 has a auto-complete feature which breaks the emacs sub-shell, you can fix this by changing this line

```
python-shell-interpreter-args "--colors=Linux --profile=default"
```

and add `--simple-prompt`.

It will allow you to see ipython correctly but for some reason I did not get yet the auto-completion in emacs is not as effective as it used to be.

Comment: Can only the output of the code show up on the minibuffer rather than in the python shell?

Answer (score 30):

> How do you run Python code using Emacs?

I'm running Emacs 26, vanilla dev version (self compiled from source cloned from [Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=emacs)).

(Note that in emacs docs, we usually see, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> denoted as C-c)

In Python mode (which I usually enter by using C-x C-f to "find" a (possibly new) file ending in .py), you can start a Python shell with and then execute your buffer's
`if __name__ == '__main__':` with:

- C-c C-p (which executes run-python to create a shell with Inferior Python major mode, Shell-Compile minor mode)
- C-u C-c C-c (which executes python-shell-send-buffer with a prefix argument)

We require the prefix argument to send the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to the inferior Python shell.

We can see all of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> commands with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd>

> ```
> C-c C-c       python-shell-send-buffer
> C-c C-d       python-describe-at-point
> C-c C-f       python-eldoc-at-point
> C-c C-j       imenu
> C-c C-l       python-shell-send-file
> C-c C-p       run-python
> C-c C-r       python-shell-send-region
> C-c C-s       python-shell-send-string
> C-c C-t       Prefix Command
> C-c C-v       python-check
> C-c C-z       python-shell-switch-to-shell
> C-c <     python-indent-shift-left
> C-c >     python-indent-shift-right
>
> C-c C-t c python-skeleton-class
> C-c C-t d python-skeleton-def
> C-c C-t f python-skeleton-for
> C-c C-t i python-skeleton-if
> C-c C-t m python-skeleton-import
> C-c C-t t python-skeleton-try
> C-c C-t w python-skeleton-while
> ```

Inspecting the help for python-shell-send-buffer (by clicking it), we see:

> ```
> python-shell-send-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> ‘python.el’.
>
> (python-shell-send-buffer &optional SEND-MAIN MSG)
>
> Send the entire buffer to inferior Python process.
> When optional argument SEND-MAIN is non-nil, allow execution of
> code inside blocks delimited by "if __name__== '__main__':".
> When called interactively SEND-MAIN defaults to nil, unless it’s
> called with prefix argument.  When optional argument MSG is
> non-nil, forces display of a user-friendly message if there’s no
> process running; defaults to t when called interactively.
> ```

According to the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) C-u is a prefix argument - and seems to be the most generic one.

A workaround that lets us avoid using the prefix argument C-u is using parentheses:

```
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

instead of the usual:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then C-c C-c by itself executes the main function.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation.  I'm a bit puzzled why the `C-u` prefix for `C-c C-c` is needed.  The docstring says "this will escape the Python idiom of if
__name__ == ’__main__’ to be false to avoid accidental execution
of code", but executing code is the whole point of `C-c C-c`.  Do you know whether there is an emacs way of avoiding the `C-u` prefix rather than changing the Python syntax to non-standard?  `C-c C-c` is soo much faster than `C-u C-c C-c`...

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>&</kbd> are underrated. Often you just want to start the current script you are working on, no need to complicate things.

Of course, you can use `M-x compile`, as long as you don't have to provide interactive input. If you *do* have to provide interactive input, `M-x shell` is your friend.

If you want to run stuff with one button press, check out <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> to record a keyboard macro and replay it (the macro can also be bound to a key, e.g. <kbd>F5</kbd>).

In each of these cases, there is no "magic" taking place. Emacs does not know how to "compile" or "run" python scripts. You have to provide/overwrite a sensible command line invocation, like:

```
Compile Command: ipython <yourscriptname>.py
```

The python subshell is cool where a REPL development style makes sense, but at least on Windows `matplotlib`, `tkinter` and other libraries that have to deal with the Windows Message Loop tend to block/hang upon displaying GUI elements.

Answer (score 4):

Once you open your python file in Emacs, you will need to start the python process with:
`M-x run-python` or `C-c C-p`, which creates an inferior python shell buffer. This buffer will be created by a horizontal split, and the active buffer will be the one containing the python file.

Then you can do `C-c C-c`, which will send the current python buffer to the inferior python shell below. This is where you will see the output of your python file.

To switch to and from your python file buffer and the inferior python shell buffer, you can do `C-x o`.

If you accidentally close one of the buffers, you can switch between buffers with `C-x C-<left_arrow>` and `C-x C-<right_arrow>` and perform operations on the python buffer like the ones mentioned by [Aaron Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45003844/9652688).

**NOTE**:

1. Running GNU Emacs 26.2 without any extensions.
2. Did not define `if (__name__ == '__main__'):` block