# Is there any python IDE that supports "highlight and run"?

Tags: python, r, ide, rstudio

I used to be a heavy R programmer and really used to the Rstudio's "highlight and run" feature. I just wonder if there any python IDE that has similar feature that allows you to select part of the code in a script and run and show the results in a console?

Comment: This will be possible in the next release of RStudio (v1.2), which is currently available as a [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html) you can highlight and run by pressing F9. I also heard a rumour that RStudio is going to be able to run python soon but I'm not sure if it's true

Answer (score 0):

Try [GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) - very powerful text editor. Using this editor you can run the selected region of code in the python shell. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669809/how-do-you-run-python-code-using-emacs) for more details.