# Emacs Doom Run Python in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, emacs

System: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Python3: Python 3.7.4

My emacs config ( according to https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/212 );

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/python3" flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

Trying to use run-python in emacs doom. Having:

```
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python.el: native completion setup failed, <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>: No module named 'readline'
Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native-enable’ was t and "python3" is not part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.  Native completions have been disabled locally.
```

import readline works perfectly in python3 in terminal.

Default python 2.7.10 doesn't work too (no my emacs config).

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import codecs, os;__pyfile = codecs.open('''/var/folders/y3/g447wqxd4l97rk7th2fszwb00000gn/T/pyQo4DAR''', encoding='''utf-8''');__code = __pyfile.read().encode('''utf-8''');__pyfile.close();os.remove('''/var/folders/y3/g447wqxd4l97rk7th2fszwb00000gn/T/pyQo4DAR''');exec(compile(__code, '''/var/folders/y3/g447wqxd4l97rk7th2fszwb00000gn/T/pyQo4DAR''', 'exec'));
python.el: native completion setup failed, <type 'exceptions.Exception'>: libedit based readline is known not to work,
      see etc/PROBLEMS under "In Inferior Python mode, input is echoed".
>>>
```

How to make emacs doom run python3 right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it to python3

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i")
```

you can set it at **init.el**

[How do you run Python code using Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669809/how-do-you-run-python-code-using-emacs)